# Is "robins" in the text below a symbol?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is the word "robins" in the text below a metaphor and if so what does it stand for?
The only robin found in dictionaries are birds.

> "The king was in the habit of filling high posts with men of no [titled] account so that he might, if the fancy took him, dismiss them as he would a valet." The men treated like valets in fact were *robins*, at the top of the bourgeoisie.
>
> — Richard Sennett, [Respect in a World of Inequality](https://books.google.it/books?id=2h5rlr5Snc8C&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=dismiss%20them%20would%20%20valet%20robins&source=bl&ots=PRISyBRCNs&sig=ZQWeOiYWqmZVM_oSXsW0du_BKaI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjP4N_a4dDOAhVDVxQKHTHrB7EQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=dismiss%20them%20would%20%20valet%20robins&f=false), Penguin, p.71.

Comment: Every written word is a symbol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a word that is almost certainly not in the English lexicon.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And yet it appears in an English book, it's explained in an English reference, the *Chicago Manual of Style* has advice on typesetting such words, and the question is about a collision with an English word. If someone asks about the motto of the Order of the Garter, are you going to vote to close that too? Because I think the Queen would be unamused.

Comment: Shall we conduct a straw poll comparing how many regulars on ELU have encountered 'Honi soit qui mal y pense ' as opposed to how many have come across this usage of 'robin'? The former is given in Collins, ODO, RHK Webster's, M-W, Dictionary.com ... as well as encyclopedias.  How many English dictionaries can you find giving the relevant sense of 'robin'? Jacinto says 'Robin is a French word'.  And I'd say that's restrictively true for this sense.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm not sure a poll of this site would do it for me. I expect that a number of regulars have run across the motto, and I'm not surprised that the motto appears in dictionaries. But do any of the words, which are no more English than *robin* in this sense. Which is essentially what the OP was moved to ask about a text otherwise in English.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently not. From the Wikipedia [entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_nobility) on the French nobility:

> Commoners were referred to as roturiers. Magistrates and men of law were sometimes called **robins**.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any evidence that this usage is English.

Comment: *Robin* is a French word. [Larousse:](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/robin/69638?q=robin#68885) a member of the robed nobility; a member of parliament in the French Ancient Régime; (literary) man in a robe, a magistrate.